# SNMP OID for VMware Tools on a virtual machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, snmp, net-snmp

I have an ESXi host running several VMs. I use snmp to query that host for information. I need to find if VMware Tools is installed on some virtual machine. Is that possible? and If so, which OID is it?

In the [documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.dcadmin.doc_41/vsp_dc_admin_guide/snmp_config/r_vmware-vminfo-mib.html) there are some entries that say things like

> Reports the configured virtual hardware MAC address. If VMware Tools is not running, the value is zero or empty.

But I couldn't find anything that would explicitly query whether VMware tools is installed on a certain VM.

Comment: Does it *have* to be SNMP?

Comment: @GregL preferably, since I'm already using it to query other info. But if there is some other way to get this information then I can give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, SNMP would be handy (I'd love it to report some of that stuff too), but I find it very limited. On the other hand, I find [PowerCLI](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi-and-esx/scripting.html) is pretty well the best thing around to interact with vSphere/ESXi in an automated way. It only works for you if you're on Windows, but there are also some Perl, Java and Ruby SDKs which would offer the same functionality from Linux.

Comment: It's definitely possible. As for which OID... Not sure. I know that Solarwinds picks it up without a problem, and that is using SNMP.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis That sounds promising. I'll take another look at the OIDs file, but I've been through it a lot of times so far. I've never used (or looked into) Solarwinds, but is there a chance Solarwinds uses a combination of the other attributes to deduce this?